# Must Apple "FairPlay Key Security Module" be implemented in C?

Tags: c#, c, drm, fairplay

I am trying to figure out how to implement a Key Security Module (KSM) for Apple FairPlay into our Key Server but as far as I understand from the sample "Server Reference Implementation" project in Apple FairPlay SDK which is written in C, they want or they advice us to implement in C.

But in one of their FairPlay slide, it says that:

> - Implement KSM logic from scratch using protocol specification, or
> - Customize the C reference implementation in the SDK (language,
>     integration)

The first sentence tells us that we can implement it from scratch.
So, does anyone implement Apple FairPlay Key Security Module in another language rather than C?

Thanks.

Comment: I have watched the FairPlay presentation and the presenter indicates that we can use whatever language we want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a Fairplay implementation in Python and specified an implementation for Java - it can be written in any language you choose as long as you have the necessary crypto libraries available (or know how to implement some of the required asymmetric cryptography).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have started writing in C#. Hope to finish this week.

Comment: I know it is not acceptable to ask questions here in comments but could you please check my forum post? Thanks https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/171342

Comment: I wrote my fairplay key server in go

Comment: @BarbarosAlp - were you able to finish your implementation? if so, please let me know, i would have a few questions.

Comment: @BarbarosAlp thank you for your reply! we have our working implementation as well (in PHP). May I ask if you tried to implement offline playback as well?

Comment: @Tamas, yes we also implemented that.

Comment: @BarbarosAlp everything works well in our implemetation (test vectors, encoding, playback etc), except offline streaming. Could you please help us how do you generate streams ready for offline streaming? What changes do you need to add in the m3u8 file (if any)?

Comment: @Tamas, you need to build proper ContentKeyDuration TLLV for persistent license. "18f06048" - PersistedRentalDuration, "3df2d9fb" persisted unlimited.